# C - Buffer getting append

Tags: c, linux, buffer, named-pipes

Im trying to create a login system in linux with named pipes.

I have a do-while loop that runs until the correct password is guessed or 3 failed atempts. The problem is that everytime i "ask" the user for a new password, the last password and current are concatenated to the buffer.

```
do
    {

        if(tentativas_login > 0)
        {
            sleep(5);
        } 
        if (tentativas_login > 2)
        {
            close(c_fifo_fd);
            close(s_fifo_fd);
            unlink(c_fifo_fname);
            sleep(5);
            return;
        }
        printf("[ADMIN]: Introduza password de acesso: ");
        scanf("%s", buffer);

        /* ---- b) GET PASSWORD ---- */
        strcat(login_flag, buffer);
        strcat(login_flag, ".");
        printf("Sent: %s\n", login_flag); //-> here is the problem
        strncpy(perg.palavra,login_flag,TAM_MAX-1); //copia a palavra lida do "buffer" para a "perg.palavra"

        /* ---- c) SEND PASSWORD ---- */
        write(s_fifo_fd, & perg, sizeof(perg));

        sleep(1);

        read_res = read(c_fifo_fd, & resp, sizeof(resp));
            if (read_res == sizeof(resp))
            {
                compare_result = strncmp(resp.palavra, "Pass Certa", 100);
                printf("[ADMIN]: Devolveu -> %s \n", resp.palavra);
                if(compare_result != 0)
                {
                    printf("[ADMIN]: Password errada! Tente novamente.\n");
                    tentativas_login++;
                }
            }
            else
            {
                printf("Sem resposta ou resposta incompreensivel[%d]\n",read_res);
            }

    }while(compare_result != 0);
```

*Example*

**Input:**

```
foo
bar
pikachu
```

**Output:**

```
login.foo.
login.foo.bar
login.foo.bar.pikachu.
```

Comment: `scanf("%s", buffer);` does not read the '\n`, does it?  Get your input by other means.

Comment: It doesnt, but im reading only 1 "word"

Comment: What I think is happening is that `scanf("%s", buffer);` does not read the `\n` for `%s` only gets non-white space text.  It is your next `scanf("%s",...` that then drops leading whitespace (the old `\n`), then reads your "bar".

Comment: @DanAlbert was right, the problem was the login_flag. I used memset and its working like a charm now =)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're using strcat() without clearing out the old buffer. In other words, the new and old buffers are being appended because that's what you told them to do. Zero out the buffer at the beginning of each loop like so:

```
memset(login_flag, 0, length_of_buffer);
```

Comment: Or use `strcpy(login_flag, buffer);`